# When should I put an attribute in a separate table?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

When should I put an attribute in a separate table? I mean is I have an attribute but whether I should put this with the rest of the attributes of a table person or whether I should put it in a separate table with person_ID as FK?

Secondly, when does an association class is formed? Can it form between a class and its multivariate attribute? Ex class book has attribute author. An author can write many books and a book can be written by many authors

Answer (score 1):

You should put an attribute in a separate table whenever you expect that one `person` could have multiple of that attribute. Otherwise, there's not much reason to separate it, and there can be some conceptual overhead in doing so. (It can be very annoying when you have to write a query that retrieves five different attributes of a `person`, if each attribute is in its own table unnecessarily.)

You should create an association table between two tables whenever the relationship between them is many-to-many. Your author–book example is a good one.

Comment: So it is ok to have association class between a class book and its multivariate attribute author?  class book {authors[1...*]}

Comment: One more thing..should I show this M:N association when doing OMT design of book and author? or should I just show like before as I did in a class book...?

Comment: @LogicianUnix: Wait, are you asking about whether your *program* -- your OO model -- should have an association class corresponding to your DB's association table? If so, then: probably not. Your `Author` class should probably have a list of `Book` references, and vice versa. One reason that you might want an `AuthorBook` class, however, is if there are additional attributes of that relationship beyond just "this author was one of the authors on this book". (For example, `AuthorBook` could be useful if you want metadata indicating which chapter(s) and which edition(s).)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what that attribute is dependant of. If it's an attribute of that entity you're creating (person) then it should go in the same table, but as you said in the case of a book where 1 book can have many authors and 1 author can write many books, you have to take into consideration the relationship between the entity and the attribute. Is it a 1 to 1 relationship, 1 to many or many to 1, etc.

This being said, if your person can only have 1 value for that attribute and that only 1 person can have that attribute, then it should go in the same table.

You should have an association table in the following situation:

1 person CAN live in more than 1 house at a time, (home and holiday house) but more people CAN also live in those houses.

Obviously, in the example above, we're ignoring the fact that 1 person cannot be in more than 1 place at a time.

As a general rule, the attribute should be dependant on "the key, the whole key and nothing but the key"

UPDATE for what @ruakh said:

It can create overhead if you separate attributes but a tool which you can use to accommodate this overhead is creating Views of the table. I'm not sure what database system you're using but MySQL has this feature. A View is a "virtual" table that you can create using SQL queries on the current database. You can combine multiple tables and you will query that View just as you would do with a normal table.

Comment: How can I represent book-author relationship in UML? Should I draw a M:N association with association class? or should I just show as book{authors[1...*]} in a class diagram?

Comment: It depends on your requirements, I believe both of them are valid representations of the concept. If you're required to make an entity relationship diagram then it depends on the style you're going to use (crow's foot or chen model) when creating the diagram.